How do I make this search bar drop down vertical?
I seem to not be able to figure this out for the life of me, I just started to learn to code recently so some answer I have found I just didn't know how to replace my current code with them and some had things I haven't learned yet, and then chatgpt never seems to be able to fix it or show me how to integrate answers I find into my full scripts properly.
.html snip
 <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="A.html">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 50px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="C.html">C</a></li>
                <li style="flex-grow: 1; position: relative;">
                    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;">
                    <ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

.css snip
#search-bar {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

#suggestions {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    list-style-type: none; 
}

#suggestions li {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#suggestions li:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.js snip
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const searchBar = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    const suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");

    const pages = [
        { name: "A", url: "A.html" },
        { name: "B", url: "B.html" },
        { name: "C", url: "C.html" },
    ];

    searchBar.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        suggestions.innerHTML = "";

        if (query) {
            const filteredPages = pages.filter(page => page.name.toLowerCase().includes(query));
            console.log("Filtered Pages:", filteredPages);
            filteredPages.forEach(page => {
                const suggestionItem = document.createElement("li");
                suggestionItem.textContent = page.name;
                suggestionItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    window.location.href = page.url;
                });
                suggestions.appendChild(suggestionItem);
            });
        }
    });

    // Handle enter key press
    searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const query = searchBar.value.toLowerCase();
            const matchedPage = pages.find(page => page.name.toLowerCase() === query);
            if (matchedPage) {
                window.location.href = matchedPage.url;
            }
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (!searchBar.contains(e.target) && !suggestions.contains(e.target)) {
            suggestions.innerHTML = "";
        }
    });
});

I have googled, attempted to integrate working scripts into my own full script, asked chatpgt for help, watch youtube videos. Played around with padding, with, wrap or no wrap, making the drop down bigger. the closes I got was when I moved <ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions"></ul> out of the header but that just caused the a weird line through the entire page, moved the search bar to partially off the screen and when clicked made it the size of the screen but the search suggestions did come in vertically... just not what I was looking for.
what it looks like in action currently:
search bar with suggestions horizontally

What that means "Want search bar drop down vertical" ?. Its already vertical, attach some screenshot or something.

screenshot added, thanks for the suggestion for the question

You don’t really need to do anything. It works already, as far as I can see. I have cleaned it up a bit, but it was working before I did that. Just make sure that you type either ‘a’, ‘b’ or ‘c’ into the search box.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const searchBar = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    const suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");

    const pages = [
        { name: "A", url: "A.html" },
        { name: "AA", url: "AA.html" },
        { name: "AAA", url: "AAA.html" },
        { name: "B", url: "B.html" },
        { name: "BB", url: "BB.html" },
        { name: "BBB", url: "BBB.html" },
        { name: "C", url: "C.html" },
        { name: "CC", url: "CC.html" },
        { name: "CCC", url: "CCC.html" },
    ];

    searchBar.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        suggestions.innerHTML = "";

        if (query) {
            const filteredPages = pages.filter(page => page.name.toLowerCase().includes(query));
            console.log("Filtered Pages:", filteredPages);
            filteredPages.forEach(page => {
                const suggestionItem = document.createElement("li");
                suggestionItem.textContent = page.name;
                suggestionItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    window.location.href = page.url;
                });
                suggestions.appendChild(suggestionItem);
            });
        }
    });

    // Handle enter key press
    searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const query = searchBar.value.toLowerCase();
            const matchedPage = pages.find(page => page.name.toLowerCase() === query);
            if (matchedPage) {
                window.location.href = matchedPage.url;
            }
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (!searchBar.contains(e.target) && !suggestions.contains(e.target)) {
            suggestions.innerHTML = "";
        }
    });
});
header, nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: aliceblue;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}

.search-widget {
  position: relative;
}

#search-bar {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#suggestions {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 10;
  left: 4px;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  display: none;
}

#suggestions:has(li) {
  display: block;
}

#suggestions li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#suggestions li:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
<header>
  <a class="logo" href="A.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </a>
  <nav>
    <a href="A.html">A</a></li>
    <a href="B.html">B</a></li>
    <a href="C.html">C</a></li>
    <span class="search-widget">
      <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" size="15">
      <ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions"></ul>
    </span>
  </nav>
</header>




Weird mine still stays horizontally.... if I could I would add a picture to show how it looks.

You can edit your post to include a picture ... and yes, you should do this. Keep improving your question until it is as good as it can be.

thanks I added an image to show how it looks

Use your browser inspector to see which style rules are being applied to #suggestions and its li children. One of them is probably inheriting a rule from somewhere else. For example, is something applying display: flex to #suggestions? If so, you could override that with display: block, or roll with flex and simply add flex-direction: column.

thanks, this fixed it, after you said it could be inheriting a rule I realized the search bar is part of the header which has a horizontal style, so adding the < display: block > fixed it

Okay, so now our task is to improve this post (your question) so that it makes sense for those who come after us. For the benefit of the community. Can you please edit your post to include the code for the relevant header styles which, when inherited, caused the problem in the first place? That way, the code in your post will be able to be used to demonstrate the problem you are describing. I will then revise my answer to shorten it and clearly point out the problem.

If brett's responses is not working for you then try this. Addition to brett's code I haved added display:flex with flex-direction: column to #suggestions:has(li) which should force it to align vertically. Also brett's response was working fine in my system.
Below is working example.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .mainDiv {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #1e1e1e;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        header,
        nav {
            display: flex;
            gap: 1em;
            align-items: center;
        }

        header {
            justify-content: space-between;
            background: aliceblue;
            padding-right: 1em;
        }

        .logo img {
            display: block;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .search-widget {
            position: relative;
        }

        #search-bar {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        #suggestions {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-top: 0;
            width: calc(100% - 8px);
            position: absolute;
            box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            z-index: 10;
            left: 4px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: white;
            display: none;
            display:flex;
        }

        #suggestions:has(li) {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #suggestions li {
            padding: 8px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            list-style: none;
            color: #000;
            text-align: left;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #suggestions li:hover {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="mainDiv">
        <header>
  <a class="logo" href="A.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </a>
  <nav>
    <a href="A.html">A</a></li>
    <a href="B.html">B</a></li>
    <a href="C.html">C</a></li>
    <span class="search-widget">
      <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" size="15">
      <ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions"></ul>
    </span>
  </nav>
</header>


    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const searchBar = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    const suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");

    const pages = [
        { name: "A", url: "A.html" },
        { name: "AA", url: "AA.html" },
        { name: "AAA", url: "AAA.html" },
        { name: "B", url: "B.html" },
        { name: "BB", url: "BB.html" },
        { name: "BBB", url: "BBB.html" },
        { name: "C", url: "C.html" },
        { name: "CC", url: "CC.html" },
        { name: "CCC", url: "CCC.html" },
    ];

    searchBar.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        suggestions.innerHTML = "";

        if (query) {
            const filteredPages = pages.filter(page => page.name.toLowerCase().includes(query));
            filteredPages.forEach(page => {
                const suggestionItem = document.createElement("li");
                suggestionItem.textContent = page.name;
                suggestionItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    window.location.href = page.url;
                });
                suggestions.appendChild(suggestionItem);
            });
        }
    });

    // Handle enter key press
    searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const query = searchBar.value.toLowerCase();
            const matchedPage = pages.find(page => page.name.toLowerCase() === query);
            if (matchedPage) {
                window.location.href = matchedPage.url;
            }
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (!searchBar.contains(e.target) && !suggestions.contains(e.target)) {
            suggestions.innerHTML = "";
        }
    });
});
    </script>

</body>

</html>



